# No covering map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{S}^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology

How should I show that there is no covering from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{S}^2$? Hatcher's algebraic topology theorem 1.10 says that there is no one-to-one continuous map from  $\mathbb{S}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$, would this theorem be useful?

Comment: Do you know about $\pi_2$?

Comment: Do you know that $S^2$ is simply-connected ?

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f: R^2 \to S^2$ is a covering map. If the degree of the covering map is one, then the map must be a homeomorphism. Suppose the degree of the map is at least two. Then given $x \in S^2$, the preimage contains at least two points, call then $x_1$ and $x_2$. Choose any path in $R^2$ between $x_1$ and $x_2$. This projects to a loop in $S^2$ based at $x$. Since $S^2$ is simply connected, this loop is contractible. But since we have a covering map, the homotopy between the projected loop downstairs to the constant loop lifts to a homotopy upstairs which fixes $x_1$ and $x_2$ along the way, but the lift of the constant loop is clearly constant. This is a contradiction. Thus the degree of the covering map is one, so $R^2$ is homeomorphic to $S^2$ which is also a contradiction. Hence no such $f$ can exist.